# Spring How to autowire a component without using @Component or other derivatives

Tags: java, spring

I would like to autowire a component (still using the @Autowired annotation), but not require it to have the @Component (or other similar annotations) on it. How would I do this?

```
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private class B b;

}

@Component
public class B {

}
```

This would be convenient in order to allow autowiring of class A without requiring the creation of A, unless we needed it (in otherwise on the fly by reflection using the class name).

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Please clarify.

Comment: It sounds that what you really want is either `@Profile` or `@Conditional`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't sure, If I correctly understood to your question. But if you want inject bean `B` without marking bean `A` via some annotation, or xml definition, you can use **[SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)**

```
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private class B b;

    public A{
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); 
    }

}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for minus one caveat. I knew what class that I needed an instance created and autowired. However, if the class's constructor had the @Autowired annotation, I would not have been able to create an instance of the constructor without retrieving the needed components. I was hoping there was a call that I could make that would do all that work for me. But this answer is working perfect for what I need at this time.

Answer (score 9):

Injection and autowiring do not *require* `@Component`. They require beans. `@Component` states that the annotated type should have a bean generated for it. You can define beans in other ways: with a `<bean>` declaration in an XML context configuration, with a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class, etc.

Your last sentence doesn't make much sense. You can't process injection targets in a bean without creating a bean. You also can't inject a bean without creating it. (Applied to scopes, bean may refer to the target source/proxy and not the actual instance.) Perhaps you want `@Lazy`.

Comment: Probably this question origins from Guice injection framework: there you CAN inject beans without any preconfiguration on the way of bean creation. I.e. if you have a bean with default contructor - you can inject it with Inject annotation. You dont need to create a config with "create that bean" or place "component" annotation on the bean which participates in DI. This valid only for beans with default constructors.

Comment: @MiamiBeach is it possible in spring?